# Drop Down Menu returns a null error

Tags: javascript, null, drop-down-menu

When I run the Firefox error console, I get this error on my drop down menu: ddmenuitem is null. Other than that, the page seems to run fine.

The error I receive is on the line where it says: ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';

```
   var timeout  = 500;
    var closetimer  = 0;
    var ddmenuitem  = 0;

    // open hidden layer
    function mopen(id)
    {   
        // cancel close timer
        mcancelclosetime();

        // close old layer
        if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';

        // get new layer and show it
        ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
        ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';

    }
    // close showed layer
    function mclose()
    {
        if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    // go close timer
    function mclosetime()
    {
        closetimer = window.setTimeout(mclose, timeout);
    }

    // cancel close timer
    function mcancelclosetime()
    {
        if(closetimer)
        {
            window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
            closetimer = null;
        }
    }

    // close layer when click-out
    document.onclick = mclose;
```

Comment: Can you post a working example (at least with HTML and JavaScript) on http://www.jsfiddle.com/? It is much easier to debug code when you can actually run it.

Comment: Here is a working example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mfgDG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no element with `id=m2`: `<a href="photo_gallery_pg1.html" onmouseout="mclosetime()" onmouseover="mopen('m2')">`

Comment: Thank you. I was able to fix it.

Comment: @TheCount: If this answer was helpful, you should upvote it. If it solved your question, you should [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).